# How to change font of settings of notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I'd like to know how to change the font size of the settings page. The picture shows how small it is.

*****(I thought id reword this question like (Mokubai) said )

How to increase the font the application uses for menus and the settings screens

[image: see picture]

Comment: They’re normal-sized though...? If you feel that they are too small, you should probably look into DPI scaling instead of font sizes.

Comment: Am I the only one that noticed that this is running notepad++ under Linux?  I bet that Wine is controlling the system font sizes.  [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/changing-font-size-in-wine-485257/) might help if my hunch is correct.

Comment: Just to add to @SeñorCMasMas. It seems like a Ubuntu Linux. You can try this [settings to increase application fonts](https://vitux.com/how-to-change-text-size-in-ubuntu/)  .

Comment: Did you get this work? I have the same issue. Running Npp on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

To change the font size, go to *Settings | Style Configurator...* and select *Global Styles | Global override* for the general-purpose font and style. You can also specify a particular font and style by language, function and so forth.

To change the *displayed text size* without altering the font, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while rolling the mouse wheel, which also works in many other applications across differing operating systems.

BTW, *Inconsolata* is a useful font to clearly distinguish numbers from letters, e.g. 1 and l, O and 0.

[image: Notepad++ Font Configuration]

Comment: It seems that he's found the style configurator, his text font is ***huge***, but what he actually wants is to increase the font the application uses for menus and the settings screens which this does not seem to touch. I admit I had started writing a nearly identical answer before I saw it.

Comment: you are right @Mokubai I want to increase the font the application uses for menus and the settings screens.

Comment: For menu items, Windows OS controls font size. Ease of Access also includes a magnifier. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028566/windows-10-change-the-size-of-text

Comment: Yes @DrMoishe_Pippik, but note that his picture is not Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested because i'm running it in ubuntu from snap I found I can run winecfg in npp snap like this `notepad-plus-plus winecfg` then change  screen resolution dpi.